# npm ERR! E404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/corsexpress - Not found 'corsexpress@*' is not in this registry

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, nodemon

I'm trying to create Full Stack MERN Project using React + Redux, Node, Express, MongoDB.

When I use below command, I'm getting an error with a warning.

> > `npm install body-parser corsexpress mongoose nodemon`

> npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/corsexpress - Not found
> npm ERR! 404
> npm ERR! 404  'corsexpress@*' is not in this registry.
>
> npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to use the `cors` middleware, run `npm install cors`.

Comment: There's also `cors-express`

Comment: @Eldar B. I installed `npm install cors`  
@robertklep afterwards I installed `npm install cors-express`  

and I'm in the root directory where package.json located. But still I'm getting the error.

Comment: @Yazz you probably have `corsexpress` still in your `package.json` file. Remove it from there.

Comment: @robertklep Thank you. Issue fixed by removing 'corsexpress' from pacakge.json

Answer (score 0):

Typing command `npm install body-parser cors express mongoose nodemon` instead of typing `npm install body-parser corsexpress mongoose nodemon` 
Afterwards issue fixed by removing 'corsexpress' from pacakge.json dependencies.